# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.No solution works for me on the internet

Tags: django

In my forms with the same token I add the @csrf_exemp, but since in login I am using the Django default I do not have a login view, I have put the token in each template and deactivated the MIDDLEWARE in settings and nothing to solve the problem too I have the host fine, I can register but not logging in nor in the django admin it gives me the same error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecfEc.png)

```
{% extends "layout.html" %} {% block content %} {% load static %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %}

 <main style="min-height: 100vh">
  <section>
   <div class="container p-4" style="min-height: 100vh">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-12 col-md-6 offset-md-3">
       <div class="card bg-black">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="h3">Login</h2>
          <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %} {{ form | crispy }}
            <a href="{% url 'main' %}">Home</a>
            |
            <a href="{% url 'sign_up' %}">Sign Up</a>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="login" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </section>
</main>

{%endblock%}
```

Comment: Do you have an AJAX call hooked up to this Form? IIRC, you can pass the csrf_token thru AJAX, also make sure your templates are formatted {% like_so %} , I've had issues in the past with parsing issues due to weird template spacing errors. Django in general is very buggy

Answer (score 1):

Since Heroku automatically translates https requests into http before it reaches your Django app, you need to configure Django to allow POST requests from a different scheme ([since Django 4.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#csrf-trusted-origins-changes-4-0)) by adding this to `settings.py`:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://chgeimsprueba.herokuapp.com']
```

Make sure to include the scheme `https://` !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this to your `settings.py` or `.env`:

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['chgeimsprueba.herokuapp.com']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['chgeimsprueba.herokuapp.com']
```

Check if I hadn't made a typo, getting those from your screenshot was not so easy :)

Comment: [Starting from Django 4.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#csrf-trusted-origins-changes-4-0), you need to include the scheme (http:// or https://) in `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS`.

Comment: @KoenDeWit by the way, an upvote on your post is mine.